# Getting no pubspec.yaml found when creating new flutter project

Tags: android, ubuntu, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm getting no pubspec.yaml found when I want to create new flutter project.

[image]

Here are flutter details

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I presume the flutter directory is not the flutter sdk?

Comment: You can run the create command with `-v` to print detailed information. Looks like the project files are not being created.